# Grails Spring Security Facebook Plugin - Connect button doesn't redirect to Facebook

Tags: spring, facebook, maven, grails, spring-security

I am successfully using Spring Security for register in login. Now I want to implement a login and register with Facebook Accounts via Spring Security Facebook Plugin.

I successfully ran the ([demo application](https://github.com/splix/grails-facebook-authentication-example)) but when I try to follow the [documentation](http://splix.github.io/grails-spring-security-facebook/) I do not get directed to Facebook inside my own app to perform a login, but always to:

http://localhost:8080/MYAPP/j_spring_security_facebook_redirect

Because I am using maven my dependencies are in a pom.xml, relevant section looks like following:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-RC4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Facebook Spring Social Plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-facebook</artifactId>
        <version>0.17</version>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
```

I also implemented the FacebookUser domain:

```
class FacebookUser {

long uid
String accessToken
Date accessTokenExpires

static belongsTo = [User]

static constraints = {
    uid unique: true
}

/* static mapWith = "mongo" */
}
```

Inside my view I have following code for the connect button:

```
<facebookAuth:connect />
```

And my Config.groovy:

```
grails {
plugin {
    springsecurity {
        facebook {
            domain.classname='de.<MYDOMAIN>.<MYAPP>.FacebookUser'
            host='<MYDOMAIN>.de'

            domain.appUserConnectionPropertyName = 'User'
            appId = "<MYFBAPPID>"
            secret = "<MYFBSECRET>"
```

So I don't understand where the mapping of "j_spring_security_facebook_redirect " is done in the demo app, and what is missing in my app do open the Facebook website instead of http://localhost:8080/MYAPP/j_spring_security_facebook_redirect

Thanks for any hints!

**UPDATE:**

Problems seem to be in my Config.groovy, because if I delete the configured providerNames and filterNames it works, but I there are configs that are needed so I cant delete them and need to add the missing filters and provider.

```
graisl.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = ['...', '...']
graisl.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.filterNames = ['...', '...']
```

I updated them with the needed filters an provider data (logged them in the demo app) but it does not find them:

```
providerNames = [
                'tokenAuthenticationProvider',
                'daoAuthenticationProvider',
                'rememberMeAuthenticationProvider',
                'FacebookAuthProvider'
        ]

        filterChain.filterNames = [
                'securityContextPersistenceFilter',
                'logoutFilter',
                'authenticationProcessingFilter',
                'tokenAuthenticationFilter',
                'basicAuthenticationFilter',
                'rememberMeAuthenticationFilter',
                'anonymousAuthenticationFilter',
                'exceptionTranslationFilter',
                'filterInvocationInterceptor',
                /* Facebook Security Filters */
                'MutableLogoutFilter',
                'FacebookAuthRedirectFilter',
                'RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter',
                'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter',
                'GrailsRememberMeAuthenticationFilter',
                'GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter',
                'ExceptionTranslationFilter',
                'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
        ]
```

Startup error:

```
ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the  application: No bean named 'FacebookAuthProvider' is defined
```

Message: No bean named 'FacebookAuthProvider' is defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it, this is my relevant Config.groovy for **grails.plugin.springsecurity** ...  now:

```
            providerNames = [
                'tokenAuthenticationProvider',
                'daoAuthenticationProvider',
                'rememberMeAuthenticationProvider',
                /* Facebook Security Provider */
                'facebookAuthProvider'
        ]

        filterChain.filterNames = [
                'securityContextPersistenceFilter',
                'logoutFilter',
                'authenticationProcessingFilter',
                'tokenAuthenticationFilter',
                'basicAuthenticationFilter',
                'rememberMeAuthenticationFilter',
                'anonymousAuthenticationFilter',
                'exceptionTranslationFilter',
                'filterInvocationInterceptor',
                /* Facebook Security Filters */
                'facebookAuthRedirectFilter',
                'securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter',
                'exceptionTranslationFilter',
        ]
```